# Securing cloud run service for end users and other services

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-run

I have a group of Cloud Run services that need to be able to take requests from end uses, via Firebase auth, but also take requests from each other. I know how to authenticate end users using ID tokens. However, I'm not sure how to authenticate for requests between services. The tutorial on service-to-service calls use a private service, but I would need to set the services to 'unauthenticated requests' to allow user requests, so I'm not sure how I would authenticate the tokens from google-auth-library. Anyone have any ideas on the best way to handle this?

Comment: Services also use Identity Tokens to authenticate to Cloud Run. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service

Answer (score 2):

```
def auth_and_trigger(self):
#the other cloud run url you wanna trigger
receiving_service_url = 'https://cloudrun-url-uc.a.run.app/download'

# Set up metadata server request
# See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature
metadata_server_token_url = 'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience='

token_request_url = metadata_server_token_url + receiving_service_url
token_request_headers = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

# Fetch the token
token_response = requests.get(token_request_url, headers=token_request_headers)
jwt = token_response.content.decode("utf-8")

# Provide the token in the request to the receiving service
receiving_service_headers = {'Authorization': f'bearer {jwt}'}

try:
   service_response = requests.post(url=receiving_service_url,
                                 json={'okay':'bro'},
                                 headers=receiving_service_headers
                                 )
logging.info(service_response.content)

except Exception as error:
    logging.error(error)
```

Using this code and Using the JWT Token, you're basically calling another cloud service (In your case, another cloud run service).

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 types of authentication, you need 2 endpoints. If you use Firebase Auth, you can use API Gateway (or Cloud Endpoint) (I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1) on that, with cloud Endpoint, but it's similar with API Gateway) with a [security definition that use FirebaseAuth](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase). And set your Cloud Run service protected and requires an ID token everytime.

Or, you need 2 Cloud Run services. The first one accept request from User and is set in allow unauthenticated, and it forward the valid request (after user validation) to the 2nd Cloud Run deployed in protected mode, only called with authenticated request (From all the Cloud Run service).

Comment: So if I used API Gateway with the firebase security definition, I couldn't send requests between the services behind the gateway? If all the cloud run services were private, could they not answer to both the gateway and each other? I was thinking I could just grant them both the "invoker" role in IAM. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The request is forwarded from API Gateway to the backend (your Cloud Run). And the call from the API Gateway is authenticated with an ID_TOKEN generated by the API Gateway itself. You can't grand firebase user with the IAM invoker role, it's not Google Account.