# Using Firebase Auth id tokens to authenticate (multiple) Cloud Run services

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-run

Related to [Security Cloud Run services for end-users and other services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66675992/securing-cloud-run-service-for-end-users-and-other-services)

I'm using:

- Firebase Auth to generate id tokens for users with Google, Microsoft, GitHub ... identities
- Cloud Endpoints on Cloud Run to invoke (Cloud Run) gRPC services
- Firebase Auth users are auth'd by one of my services

Where I'm struggling....

My app provides 1 or more Cloud Run services that the app's users should be able to curl. But authenticating Cloud Run services require per-service id tokens; the id token's audience must use the Cloud Run service URL and the Cloud Run service URL is service-specific.

It seems as though I ought to be able to exchange the Firebase Auth id token for (Google Account) id tokens (with appropriate audiences) that can then be used to invoke the Cloud Run service. The proxy could also run on Cloud Run and it would use my app's auth service to verify whether the id token user should be issued with a Google id token.

Guillaume Blaquire's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66677553/609290) proposes either Coud Endpoints or a proxy similar to what I describe above. However, Cloud Endpoints requires that the backend services be known at deploy time (which these Cloud Run services won't be) and I want to provide the user with the id token so that they can use `curl` or some other tool to make the auth'd request.

Cloud Run has some compelling documentation for [Authenticate](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) (sic.) but I want something between:

- [Authenticating users](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users) -- I have the JWT but I want to receive a Google id token for the Cloud Run service
- [Authenticating service-to-service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) which Guillaume's alternative proposal in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66677553/609290).

Comment: I personally haven't used Cloud Endpoints and instead invoke and handle Authentication within each public (can be invoked unauthenticated) Cloud Run instance (behind a domain). The Cloud Run should launch, parse the request, in particular [the request's Authorization header](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/490ea0b31400b4f925cb42e20eeae18f18742e88/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L71), and then either action or terminate the request. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68276538/3068190) for details on handling both HTTP and service-service requests.

Comment: @samthecodingman that's insightful. I think it's a good solution to my problem particularly since I'm planning to be the authenticator and the service names are obscure to help mitigate abuse. Thank you

Comment: @samthecodingman can you post your solution as answer? This way it can be easily seen by the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than place your Cloud Run behind Cloud Endpoints, where you have to know the Cloud Run instances ahead of time, you can handle the request and authentication inside the Cloud Run instance itself.

To be able to handle Firebase Authentication tokens inside the Cloud Run instance, they must be setup so that they can be invoked unauthenticated. Then, inside the Cloud Run, it should launch a web server, parse the incoming request (paying attention to the `Authorization` header - [Firebase Auth sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/490ea0b31400b4f925cb42e20eeae18f18742e88/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L71)) and then either action or terminate the request.

To achieve this, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68276538/3068190) for details on how you can handle both HTTP and service-service requests. Alternatively, you could just deploy the [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) image from which that thread's code is based.

If you want cleaner URLs, host multiple endpoints within a single Cloud Run instance and then place that instance behind Cloud Endpoints or you can take a more manual approach via a custom domain using a service like [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run).

Comment: It looks as though your approach is going to work for me. I'm using Go and will add Firebase Auth's [`VerifyIDToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#go) to my interceptor|filter. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this approach allows somebody to DDoS your Cloud Run service and you will be paying for all those (potentially billions) unauthenticated, but still CPU consuming, DDoS requests?

Comment: @IllyaS Unfortunately yes, however Google Front End has some basic DDoS protections in place. Google Cloud Armor and Cloudflare both provide more robust protections. You can obfuscate your endpoints and make them unguessable. You can run a single multi-purpose Cloud Run behind Cloud Endpoints. You can even place the Cloud Run instance behind Firebase Hosting's CDN. Ultimately the solution you use is up to you. OP appears to have a low-risk, low-reward application. If you have an application worth someone DDoSing you - use Cloud Armor or Cloudflare in front of your instances.

Comment: As a quick hypothetical, for the setup described here where a request is confirmed in the Cloud Run itself, we can perform a quick calculation to determine how much each request would take to reject. Assuming use of a basic instance (1 vCPU, 1 GiB) and that a bad request takes 10s to reject, each request would cost $0.000025 to handle (or $25 per million requests). You can use that to roughly gauge if it is worth implementing protections or not for your use case.